# k means clustering input?

Tags: matlab, sign, k-means

I want to do k means clustering on a 1024 * 1024 * 3 .ppm files. I must admit the points in this image are very low in intensity. Now, i read the picture, then resize it, so that alteast matlab can display it. Then is the line of code to reshape it and convert it to double so that i can pass it to the inbuilt matlab kmeans function.

```
img1 = imread('picture.ppm');
img= imresize(img1,0.15);
imshow(img);
imf = double(reshape(img,size(img,1)*size(img,2),size(img,3)));
imf = imresize(imf,.15);
[m,n,z]=size(imf)
```

But i am running into a lot of errors. 
1) The intensity of the points is very low. After i do this :

```
Y=Y*255; %y being of the same dimension as my img
imf1 = Y-imf;
```

most of the my picture is white with low intensity points scattered.Any other way i can increase the intensity of those points?

2) What do i do with the image so that it can pass as a valid input to various kmeans algorithms? I need two clusters, of black and red points.

Comment: correction the image is of .ppm extension

Answer (score 1):

K-means does not allow you to specify the composition of the outputted clusters based on predefined criteria. It simply attempts to find centroids with minimal distances to your points. You can generally supply starting points `[0,0,0;1,0,0]` corresponding to black and red, but there is no guarantee that the final centroids will resemble the starting points.

However, if you know *a priori* what your centroids should look like, you don't need k-means. Simply calculate the distance of every one of your pixels to a black pixel and a red pixel and pick the smallest of the distances.